# Should web-applications and webapp tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge, merge-questions

Should [web-applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) (551 questions) and [webapp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp) (8 questions) tags be merged? I think so.

Comment: @MichaelT: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Though given the counts of the various tags, its even easier than going through a merge.

I've retagged all the [webapp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp) to [web-applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications).  The webapp tag will die with the zombie tag cleanup script.

If it gets recreated again (though that will take some rep to do), can rethink synonyms, merges, and blacklists.